# QBChatMessage.isMarkable() always returns false even after setting markable to true before sending message

Tags: java, android, quickblox

I'm working on an Android app, with QuickBlox SDK. While implementation of Private Chat, I'm setting the markable property of message to true by calling `message.setMarkable(true)` on a `QBChatMessage` object before sending a message.

Below is the `processMessage` override function. Here the incoming `QBChatMessage message` always has the `markable` property as `false`. Due to this, it doesn't allow the message to be 'read' using the `privateChat.readMessage()` function.

```
@Override
public void processMessage(QBPrivateChat chat, QBChatMessage message) {
    Log.w(TAG, "new incoming message: " + message);

    message.setMarkable(true);

    chatActivity.showMessage(message);
    if (message.isMarkable()) {
        try {
            privateChat.readMessage(message.getId());
        } catch (XMPPException e) {

        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {

        }
    }

}
```

Let me know what could be wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in SDK 2.2.2   2 months ago

http://quickblox.com/developers/Android#Framework_changelog

Comment: I'm using SDK version 3.3.1 but message.isMarkable()  always returns false for me even if i set message as markable true.

Comment: Are you talking about real-time messages or messages from chat history?

Comment: Because markable is applied only for real-time messages

Comment: I'm also talking about real time messages

Comment: Could you please create another ticket and provide code snippets